# Spring Boot to access OAuth2 protected resources without using HttpSecurity?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, spring-webclient

I would like to create a simple console spring boot application which should read an URL from terminal then print its data then again read another URL and print its data and so on till pressing `CTRL + C`. The [grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3) to be used should be [client credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4); the *client credentials* should be the same for every URL and should be conveyed to the application at startup using the spring boot [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) capabilities. After 1th URL read the [access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) used in the process should be reused for the subsequent URLs; when expired/invalidated the *access token* should be transparently renewed/re-generated (using the [refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.4) if provided by the authorisation server in the 1th place or again the *client credentials* grant type).

The [6.6 OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client) with e.g. [12.5 WebClient for Servlet Environments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#servlet-webclient) seems to fit the need but require to configure `HttpSecurity` (see [6.6 OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client)) which I don't need because I'm not creating a web application but kind of a [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) utility.

How would one benefit the features provided by those without having to configure `HttpSecurity`?

Comment: Short answer id say is no, you cant, longer answer wouldbe maybe with a lot of work. What you can do is run a command line in a spring boot app. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

Answer (score -1):

you can consider postman is a console application without http security config. I think you need to create your own login to store the token and then put it into the header for each restful call.

Comment: I could use curl or other means but the question is about how to do it in java with spring boot without `HttpSecurity` (I'm rewriting my question). So this is not answering the question, please remove the answer before someone rejects it.